# gcc Warning Passing argument 2 of 'alt_16550_fifo_write' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, linux, pointers, int, compiler-warnings

I am currently working on a project involving a Cyclone V ARM Cortex A9 Processor and an external device. I am relatively new in C Programming. I am using the UART interface of the processor to send and receive data from the external with help of APIs in C. When i compile my code, I get warnings that I am passing arguments that make pointer from integer without a cast in the function `alt_16550_fifo_write()`. Can someone please help?

Below is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>     // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h>     // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h>      // File control definitions
#include <errno.h>      // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h>    // POSIX terminal control definitions
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "ergo.h"
#include "alt_clock_manager.h"
#include "hwlib.h"
#include "alt_clock_group.h"
#include "alt_hwlibs_ver.h"
#include "alt_16550_uart.h"
#include "uart.h"
#include "socal/alt_clkmgr.h"
#include "socal/alt_rstmgr.h"
#include "socal/alt_uart.h"
#include "socal/hps.h"
#include "socal/socal.h"



/* commands to control the ergo bike */
#define ERGO_CMD_GET_ADDRESS   0x11
#define ERGO_CMD_RUN_DATA      0x40
#define ERGO_CMD_SET_WATT     0x51
#define UART_MAX_DATA       20
#define enable_init          TRUE


/*Global Variables*/
ergo_run_data_t ergo_run_data;
u_int8_t ergo_adr_int;

/* External Functions that are called in the main function*/
static ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_16550_reset_helper(ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle, bool enable_init);
static inline uint32_t alt_read_word_helper(const void * addr);
static ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_16550_write_divisor_helper(ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle,uint32_t divisor);
ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_clk_clock_enable(ALT_CLK_t ALT_CLK_L4_SP);
ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_clk_is_enabled(ALT_CLK_t ALT_CLK_L4_SP);
ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_clk_freq_get(ALT_CLK_t ALT_CLK_L4_SP,alt_freq_t* freq);
ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_16550_fifo_write(ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle,const char * buffer,size_t count);
void ergo_get_address(ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle);
void ergo_get_run_data(void);
void ergo_set_watt(u_int8_t ergo_adr_int, u_int8_t watt);
void ergo_reset(ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle,u_int8_t ergo_adr_int);
void ergo_break(void);


/*function to enable the SOCFPGA UART Clock*/
ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_clk_clock_enable(ALT_CLK_t ALT_CLK_L4_SP)
{


    if (alt_clk_clock_enable(ALT_CLK_L4_SP) != ALT_E_ERROR)
    {

      return ALT_E_SUCCESS;  // The operation was successfull
    }
    else
    {
      return ALT_E_ERROR;  // The operation was not successfull
    }

}

/*Function to check whether the SOCFPGA Clock is enabled*/
ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_clk_is_enabled(ALT_CLK_t ALT_CLK_L4_SP)
{
        ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle;
    handle->clock_freq = 0;

   if (alt_clk_is_enabled(ALT_CLK_L4_SP) != ALT_E_TRUE)
    {
      return ALT_E_BAD_CLK;
    }
  else
   {
    ALT_STATUS_CODE status;
    status = alt_clk_freq_get(ALT_CLK_L4_SP, &handle->clock_freq);
   }
}

//function to get the clock frequency
ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_clk_freq_get(ALT_CLK_t ALT_CLK_L4_SP,alt_freq_t* freq)
{

     ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle;
     handle->clock_freq = 0;

     ALT_STATUS_CODE status;
     status = alt_clk_freq_get(ALT_CLK_L4_SP, &handle->clock_freq);

     if (status != ALT_E_SUCCESS)
            {
                return status;
            }

}

struct uart_data_t
{

      size_t tx_count;                  /*amount of data to send*/

      char tx_buffer[UART_MAX_DATA];    /*data to send*/

      size_t rx_count;                  /*amount of data to send*/

      char rx_buffer[UART_MAX_DATA];    /*data received*/


}uart_data_t;

/*==========================UART functions======================*/

/*-----------------------------  uart_init() -------------------------*/
/**
 * Übergabeparameter:   -
 * Return:              -
 * Funktion:            Initialisiert UART-Schnittstelle
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/


int main()
{
     /* Open File Descriptor */
    int USB = open( "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK);


     //Error Handling
    if ( USB < 0 )
    {
    printf("Error beim oeffnen");
    }



        // Configure Port
    struct termios tty;
    struct termios tty_old;
    memset (&tty, 0, sizeof tty);

    // Error Handling
    if ( tcgetattr ( USB, &tty ) != 0 )
        {
       printf("error beim tcgetattr");
    }

    // Save old tty parameters
    tty_old = tty;



    ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle;
    handle->data;
    handle->fcr;
    handle->clock_freq;
    handle->location; //ALT_UART0_ADDR
    handle->device;

        //ALT_16550_DEVICE_SOCFPGA_UART0 = 0; //This option selects UART0 in the SoC FPGA



        ALT_16550_DEVICE_t device;
        ALT_STATUS_CODE status;
        alt_freq_t clock_freq;
        void *location;
        const void *  addr;
        bool enable_init;
        uint32_t baudrate = ALT_16550_BAUDRATE_9600;

        uint32_t divisor;  //((handle->clock_freq + (8 * baudrate)) / (16 * baudrate));

        printf("Program start \n");

         // Enable the UART Clock
         alt_clk_clock_enable(ALT_CLK_L4_SP);


    // Helper function to reset and Initialise the UART (UART 0)
     alt_16550_reset_helper(handle, enable_init);

    // Helper function to carryout the actual register read.
     alt_read_word_helper(addr);

    //Helper function to write the divisor in Hardware
    alt_16550_write_divisor_helper(handle,divisor);

    //Enable the UART (UART 0)
    alt_16550_enable(handle);

    //Enable the FIFO
    alt_16550_fifo_enable(handle);

    //Get the Ergometer address
    ergo_get_address(handle);

    return 0;
}


/*---------------------------  ergo_get_adr() ------------------------*/
/**
 * Übergabeparameter:   -
 * Return:              -
 * Funktion:            Holen der Ergometer-Adreesse (1 Byte)
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void ergo_get_address(ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle)
{
        struct uart_data_t data;

    /* build up data frame for address request */
    data.tx_count = 1;       // amount of data to send
    data.tx_buffer[0] = ERGO_CMD_GET_ADDRESS;
    data.rx_count = 2;        /*amount of data to receive*/

    /* get address from ergo bike */
        alt_16550_fifo_write(handle, *ERGO_CMD_GET_ADDRESS,1);
        alt_16550_fifo_read(handle,data.rx_buffer,2);

    /* save ergo address if the bike responded */
    if(data.rx_buffer[0] == ERGO_CMD_GET_ADDRESS)
    {
        ergo_adr_int = data.rx_buffer[1];
                printf("%d\n",data.rx_buffer[1]);
    }

    /* wait for 50ms */
    ergo_break();

  return;
}

/*----------------------------  ergo_reset() -------------------------*/
/**
 * Übergabeparameter:   u_int8_t ergo_adr_int
 * Return:              -
 * Funktion:            Setzt Ergometer zurück
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void ergo_reset(ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle,u_int8_t ergo_adr_int)
{
  alt_16550_fifo_write(handle,0x12,1);
  alt_16550_fifo_write(handle,ergo_adr_int,1);
 ergo_break();
return;
}

/*----------------------------  ergo_break() -------------------------*/
/**
 * Übergabeparameter:   -
 * Return:              -
 * Funktion:            Wait for about 50 ms
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void ergo_break(void)
{
    u_int16_t d1;
    u_int8_t d2;

    //wait for ~50 ms
    for(d1=0; d1 < 65535; d1++)



    {
        for(d2=0; d2 < 64; d2++)
                {
                }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Narrow. The problem. Down.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, your function prototype is

```
ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_16550_fifo_write
                 (ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle,const char * buffer,size_t count);
```

the second parameter being `const char * buffer`.

While calling this function, you're using

```
void ergo_reset(ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle,u_int8_t ergo_adr_int)
{
  alt_16550_fifo_write(handle,0x12,1);
  alt_16550_fifo_write(handle,ergo_adr_int,1);
 ergo_break();
return;
}
```

here, `0x12` and `ergo_adr_int` are not of type `const char *`.

- `0x12` is an `int`eger constant (hexadecimal constant, to be precise) <sup>#</sup>.
- `ergo_adr_int` is of `u_int8_t` type.

Hence the mismatch and the warning(s).

**To Resolve**

You need to pass a `const char *` variable as the second argument of the fuunction.

---

# :: As per `C11` standard document, chapter 6.4.4.1, *Integer constants*,

> hexadecimal-constant:
>
> hexadecimal-prefix hexadecimal-digit
>
> hexadecimal-constant hexadecimal-digit

Where

> hexadecimal-prefix: one of
>
> 0x 0X

and

> hexadecimal-digit: one of
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> a b c d e f
>
> A B C D E F

Comment: Thanks alot for your contribution. I have been able to resolve the problem and also learnt alot from it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the declaration of you `alt_16550_fifo_write` function

```
ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_16550_fifo_write(ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle,const char * buffer,size_t count);
```

The second parameter is of a pointer type but in your program you are always passing integer values:

```
alt_16550_fifo_write(handle,0x12,1);
alt_16550_fifo_write(handle,ergo_adr_int,1);
```

You need to pass a pointer to a `char`. For example:

```
alt_16550_fifo_write(handle, &(char) {0x12}, 1);
```

or

```
char x = 0x12;
alt_16550_fifo_write(handle, &x, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks alot  for your contribution. I have been able to resolve the problem and also learnt alot from it.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype for `alt_16550_fifo_write()` is:

```
ALT_STATUS_CODE alt_16550_fifo_write(ALT_16550_HANDLE_t * handle,
                                     const char * buffer, size_t count);
```

You are using it at two places:

```
alt_16550_fifo_write(handle, *ERGO_CMD_GET_ADDRESS,1);
...
alt_16550_fifo_write(handle,0x12,1);
```

The second parameter is wrong. It should be `const char * buffer`, for example some string.

Comment: Jurkovic Thanks alot  for your contributions. I have been able to resolve the problem and also learnt alot from it.